# Android, sqlite,spinner :)

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Populating Spinner From SQLite Database Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2196426/populating-spinner-from-sqlite-database-android)

I want to use 2 spinners and one edittext in my Android project.

The first spinner includes "Countries" 
The second spinner includes "Cities" but it should be affected by first spinner selection.

Then if i choose any countries from second spinner i want to give some information in "editext"

How i can do it?  I know I have to use SQLite and create a table, but I know the logical things but I couldn't write the code on Eclipse..

Comment: Have you managed to write anything yet?  What problems are you having?

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at this example from the Android Developer site;

http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/Spinner/src/com/android/example/spinner/SpinnerActivity.html

You need to set an OnItemSelectedListener for each of the Spinners and in onItemSelected() you should be able to get the spinner value and update the other Spinner/EditText.

Cheers,
H