# Spinner, Sqlite and EditText

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android, sqlite,spinner :)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5930649/android-sqlite-spinner)

Hi guys,

I want to use 2 spinners and one edittext in my Android project.

The first spinner includes "Countries" The second spinner includes "Cities" but it should be affected by first spinner selection.

Then if i choose any countries from second spinner i want to give some information in "editext"

How i can do it? I know I have to use SQLite and create a table, but I know the logical things but I couldn't write the code on Eclipse..

Answer (score 0):

Take two `Spinner` say `countrySpinner` and `citySpinner`.
bind your `countrySpinner` from DB. and use `OnItemSelectedListener` to bind the `citySpinner` from DB according to selected country. then `OnItemSelectedListener` for `citySpinner` set data in `EditText`.
Here are the tutorial for Using SQLite DB in Android

[Android SQLite Database - Tutorial](http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html)

[Android SQLite Basics](http://www.screaming-penguin.com/node/7742)