# spinner from a database within a map

Tags: android, database, dictionary, spinner

I'd like to ask if you have any useful tutorial on how to create a spinner that contains list of items from a database in a map activity class?

Thank you

Comment: [See here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2196426/593709) and [here](http://androidforbeginners.blogspot.com/2010/02/how-to-populate-spinner-widget-from.html) and [here](http://www.samcoles.co.uk/mobile/android-populate-a-spinner-from-your-sqlite-database/) and [here](http://www.developerscode.com/2011/06/bind-data-in-spinner-from-database-in.html)

Comment: Thank you i'll check them out :)