# Spinners - custom input

Tags: android, spinner, customization, android-spinner

I am new to making android apps and was trying to find out if there is a way for a user to add their own custom selections to a Spinner.
For example I want to make a database for keeping track of car maintenance.
So I want the user to be able to add/remove their own cars/trucks as needed to it.

If there is a better way to do this I am open to any suggestions.
I am using eclipse.

Thanks for any help in this matter.

Comment: Yes you can do this. Goodluck

Answer (score 0):

So two ways to do this,

First off since you are using a database I would look at using a SimpleCursorAdapter or a Loader to manage the connection and updates to the db, so you don't manually have to refresh the query, and use a SimpleCursorAdapter to power the spinner like this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/11216746/418505

Or, you could programmatically query the database and then use some UI event hook, like a button click to submit the new car/truck to then update whatever Adapter you have bound to the spinner (make sure you call [notifyDataSetChanged](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged()))

Comment: ok thank you I will look into that.  Like I said I'm new to all this so I will definitely have to read up on that.  Still learning what half these words mean lol