# How can I show the data from a sqlite file in a spinner(drop-down menu)?

Tags: android, sqlite, spinner

I am new to android. Someone please explain me how to show data from a sqlite file in a drop-down menu. The db file is in assets folder.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the data from the assets folder into sqlite.

[Ship an application with a database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513084/how-to-ship-an-android-application-with-a-database)

Use an adapter to populate the spinner.

[Populating Spinner From SQLite Database Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2196426/populating-spinner-from-sqlite-database-android)